# Why when I submit a form into a Spring MVC application I obtain this HTTP Status 404 error page?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, spring-form

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and I have the following problem trying to submit a form defined into a view.

So I have a view named `consultazione.jsp` that contains this form:

```
<form:form action="/consultazioneRicercaForm" method="post" modelAttribute="consultazioneRicercaForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">

            <label>Regioni:</label>
            <form:select path="regioneSelezionata" id="selReg">
                <form:options items="${listaRegioni}" itemLabel="desReg" itemValue="codReg" />
            </form:select>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Province:</label>
            <form:select path="provinciaSelezionata" id="selProv">

            </form:select>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Codice Meccanografico:</label>
            <form:input path="codMec" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
</form:form>
```

As you can see in the previous code when the form is submitted it is generated a POST request toward the `/consultazioneRicercaForm` with a `modelAttribute="consultazioneRicercaForm"` object that represent the form object in which are stored the values inserted in the form.

So this is my controller class:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:wifi.properties")
@Controller
public class MinisterialeController {

    @Autowired
    GeograficaService geograficaService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "consultazioneMinisteriale", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String consultazione(@ModelAttribute ConsultazioneRicercaForm consultazioneRicercaForm, Locale locale, Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("consultazioneRicercaForm", consultazioneRicercaForm);
        List<Twb1012Regione> listaRegioni = geograficaService.getListaRegioni();

        System.out.println("Numero regioni: " + listaRegioni.size());

        model.addAttribute("listaRegioni", listaRegioni);
        model.addAttribute("regioneSelezionata", new Twb1012Regione());

        return "utenteMinisteriale/consultazione";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/provinceDiUnaRegione.json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getProvince(String codiceRegione) {

        System.out.println("INTO getProvince()");

        List<Twb1013Provincia> provinceDiUnaRegioneList =  geograficaService.getListaProvinceDiUnaRegione(codiceRegione);

        try {
            String listaProvince = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(provinceDiUnaRegioneList);
            return listaProvince;
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        return "";


    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "consultazioneRicercaForm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String consultazioneRicercaForm(@ModelAttribute ConsultazioneRicercaForm consultazioneRicercaForm) {
        System.out.println(consultazioneRicercaForm.getCodMec());
        return "redirect:/consultazioneMinisteriale";
    }
}
```

As you can see this is the method that handle the previous post request representing the post submit operation:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "consultazioneRicercaForm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String consultazioneRicercaForm(@ModelAttribute ConsultazioneRicercaForm consultazioneRicercaForm) {
        System.out.println(consultazioneRicercaForm.getCodMec());
        return "redirect:/consultazioneMinisteriale";
    }
```

The problem is that when I submit the form clicking on the **submit** button I obtain this error page (but I can't see no error in the stacktrace):

```
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 - /consultazioneRicercaForm

JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000067: Status report

JBWEB000068: message /consultazioneRicercaForm

JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.
JBoss Web/7.2.2.Final-redhat-1
```

Why? What could be the problem? How can I try to fix it?

Comment: Is the application deployed as the root application? If not, then don't use an absolute path like /consultazioneRicercaForm. Use c:url (or s:url) to convert your context-relative paths to absolute paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form's `action` URL is absolute (it starts with `/`):

```
<form:form action="/consultazioneRicercaForm" method="post" ...
```

A URL starting with `/` will look for the page at root of your domain (say `http://example.com/consultazioneRicercaForm`).

In other words, if the HTML page that contains that `form` is at `http://example.com/theNameOfMyApp/consultazione.jsp`, then that `action` will post the form to `http://example.com/consultazioneRicercaForm` not `http://example.com/theNameOfMyApp/consultazioneRicercaForm` as you may be expecting.

#### How to be sure?

What is the URL of your application?

`http://example.com/consultazione.jsp` or `http://example.com/theNameOfMyApp/consultazione.jsp`?

If is the latter, then your problem is likely to be the `/` in the beginning of the URL as mentioned above.

To be more specific, in the first URL, you app is deployed to the *ROOT* context. In the second URL, your app is deployed to the `theNameOfMyApp` context.

#### 404 could be also just a nonexistent URL

It is very common for the problem to be just a typo in the `action` mapped URL. In your case, this is less likely, since your controller `MinisterialeController` has a method mapping that path:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "consultazioneRicercaForm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String consultazioneRicercaForm(
```

Just don't forget, that mapping alone enables the `consultazioneRicercaForm` path. But it still has the context of the application.

### Solution:

Assuming your application is not deployed to the ROOT context (check the *How to be sure? above*), remove the `/` from the `action` attribute of your `form`:

```
<form:form action="consultazioneRicercaForm" method="post" ...
```

This way, if the HTML page that contains that `form` is at `http://example.com/theNameOfMyApp/consultazione.jsp`, then that `action` will post the form to `http://example.com/theNameOfMyApp/consultazioneRicercaForm`.

Answer (score 0):

When you metion `/` in your url its refering from root context. So you need to have the application name in it. Either you could remove that `/`  or construct your url like

```
<spring:url value="/consultazioneRicercaForm" var="consultazioneRicercaUrl" />
<form:form action="${consultazioneRicercaUrl}" method="POST" modelAttribute="consultazioneRicercaForm">
```